# Sum of multiple rasters in QGIS Python

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator, for-loop

I would like to make the sum of 12 different rasters to get one raster as output.
I wrote the following code but it doesn't work (or better, it works, but at the end it doesn't give me any layer, but the writing "Invalid layer, Gdal provider cannot open Gdal dataset"), any suggestions to how modifying it?

```
import qgis
import gdal 
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer

suffix_input=['I_jan', 'I_feb', 'I_mar', 'I_apr', 'I_may', 'I_jun', 'I_jul', 'I_aug', 'I_sep', 'I_oct', 'I_nov' ,'I_dec']
inputpath = '/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/I/'

list=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
sum=0
for i in list:
  inputrasterfile = QgsRasterLayer(inputpath + suffix_input[i] + ".tif")

  entries = []
  ras = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
  ras.ref = 'ras@1' 
  ras.raster = inputrasterfile
  ras.bandNumber = 1
  entries.append( ras )

  sum = 'sum + ras@1'

  calc = QgsRasterCalculator( sum, '/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/CAPITANATA PROGETTO/Itot.tif', 'GTiff', inputrasterfile.extent(), inputrasterfile.width(), inputrasterfile.height(), entries )
  print(calc.processCalculation())
  iface.addRasterLayer('/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/Itot.tif')
```

Comment: Also, I just noticed you declare `entries = []` inside a loop. So that means the list is emptied at the start of each loop iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to iterate a list while having access to iteration number then use

`for i, item in enumerate(list):`

If you don't need the counter, then just do it like `for item in list:`

2. I would propose that you don't sum the rasters in a loop but instead calculate the sum with a single calculation after the loop like this:

   ```
    expr = ''
    rasters = []
    for i, suffix in enumerate(suffix_input):
        inputrasterfile = QgsRasterLayer(inputpath + suffix + ".tif", suffix)
        rasters.append(inputrasterfile)

        expr = expr + '"{}@1"+'.format(suffix)

    expr = expr.rstrip('+')

    alg_params = {
        'CELLSIZE': 0,
        'CRS': None,
        'EXPRESSION': expr,
        'EXTENT': rasters[0].extent(),
        'LAYERS': rasters,
        'OUTPUT': '/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/Itot.tif')
    }

    result = processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', alg_params)
    iface.addRasterLayer('/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/Itot.tif')
   ```

Comment: Thank you, now the code works, but at the end the raster of output Itot has all the pixels with value 1.79769e+308, can you say me where is the mistake in doing the calculations? I'm sure that input rasters have right values

Comment: Try to run some checks. For example: see if `inputrasterfile.isValid()` returns `true`

Comment: Maybe you need to set CRS or something else. Since I don't have your data it is hard to tell.

Comment: Maybe you want to sum a different band? Right now `@1` is summed. Just tossing suggestions

Comment: @LeonPowałka Your code works perfectly. I created some raster with same prefixes and some **nodata** values and raster sum is also obtained where all pixel are different to nodata values.  I think issues can be related to bad alignment of original raster.

Comment: I don't know why, if I do the same calculation manually with the Raster Calculator (not python console) it gives me the right result; I want only one band, not different band. How can I set the CRS? Sorry I am really a beginner with this stuff

Comment: After you successfully run the calculation in interface go check `Processing` -> `History`. There you will see the exact Python command that worked. Try to recreate it in your code.

Comment: @Rapu93 If you are using Leon Powałka's code you only have to load one layer in Map Canvas. QGIS automatically will select adequate CRS (from your layer, not None) when his code is running.